# Cut in a Weighted Undirected Connected Graph

Tags: graph-theory

*Background: I am a newbie to graph theory, specially in "graph cut". Please don't be too technical and fast. Thank you.*
Suppose I have a weighted undirected connected graph G=(V,E). I have a variable A that holds an integer value and I want to remove/cut all edges from the graph G whose weight are below the value of A.
Question 1: If this already exist in graph theory (I saw max-cut, min-cut, s-t cut, etc) how is it called?
Question 2: How can I formally express/define this approach using mathematical symbols.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove/cut" ?

Comment: @MrGreen I mean to "delete" the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

- a Graph `G`
- composed of a set of vertices `V`
- and a edges `E` which is a set of pairs of vertices (i.e. `E = {{x,y} : x ∈ V, y ∈ V}`).
- each edge has a weight (assumed to be a natural number) which you can specify using a function (i.e. `∀ e ∈ E : weight(e) ∈ ℕ`).

Then the graph `G'` with removed edges with weight not less than `a` (note: singular elements/values are usually denoted using lower-case whereas sets/lists/etc are usually denoted using upper-case) is given by:

- `G' = (V, { e ∈ E : weight(e) ≥ a })`
- or `G' = (V,E') : E' = { e ∈ E : weight(e) ≥ a }`

or, to make it more explicit that you are removing elements from `E`, you could be long-winded and define it as:

- `G' = (V, E \ { e ∈ E : weight(e) < a })`
- or `G' = (V,E') : E' = E \ { e ∈ E : weight(e) < a }`

Comment: @MTO Thank you very much bro! Excellent breakdown of the problem domain and very clear explanation. Ah, if only I could pay you a beer! One more question, what is the maximum running time of this procedure and how can I describe it formally. Thanks.

Comment: The running time should be `O(E)` - you need to iterate over each edge and test it's weight and then create a new data structure representing the graph. Each step - creating a new graph; testing the weight; and adding edges to the new graph - should be `O(1)` (if done efficiently) and you will repeat step for each edge (so `O(E)` in total). To state it formally you just need to write something like that but taking care to explicitly break the algorithm into its constituent parts and work from there.

Comment: Yes since each edge need to be visited, 'O(E)' seems logical in this case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to remove the edges whose weight are less than `A`. 
This has nothing to do with [cuts in graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28graph_theory%29).

I think the mathematical expression of what you want is:

```
G'(V', E') = G(V, Q) : Q = {x: x <= A and x belongs to E}
```

Comment: Yes I think I don't have to look at cuts. Thanks for the mathematical expression.